# How do I get the HTTP status code of a given URL via Spring?

Tags: spring, kotlin

I am working in a Spring @Component class and I am trying to get the HTTP status code of a particular URL for further processing. I have a function as follows:

```
fun getStatus() : String
   { 
        val webClient = WebClient.create("https://stackoverflow.com")
        val result = webClient.get()
                .exchange().map { res -> res.rawStatusCode() }

        println(result)
        return "statusGotten"
   }
```

However, rather than getting the Int value of the status code (e.g. 200, or 401), I am simply getting: "MonoMap".

I am new to both Spring and Web Programming in general, so I'm a little confused how to proceed from here. I'm aware that "result" is being returned as a "Mono", but I'm less clear about what a "Mono" is, or how I might transform it into something with more scrutable properties, as even looking at "result" in the debugger doesn't shed any light as to whether the HTTP request was actually sent or was successful:

[image]

Am I calling the webclient incorrectly? Or merely failing to parse the resultant data in a meaningful way? Any suggestions on how or where I might learn more about the underlying topics would be much appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a blocking way to do this is easy just

```
@Test
public void myTest(){

    WebClient client = WebClient.builder().baseUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/").build();

    ClientResponse resp = client
        .get()
        .uri("questions/")
        .exchange()
        .block();   

    System.out.println("Status code response is: "+resp.statusCode());
}
```

But for this you can use directly the RestTemplate instead the webclient... the recomended way to do this is non blocking what means you should return a Mono with the status and consume outside your method like for example:

```
public Mono<HttpStatus> myMethod(){

    WebClient client = WebClient.builder().baseUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/").build();

    return client
        .get()
        .uri("questions/")
        .exchange()
        .map( clientResp -> clientResp.statusCode());   
}
```

The way of consume this Mono depends of your code...

Comment: Realizing that I should be returning (and consuming) a Mono instead of primitive data type was what was missing! I tweaked it to be a Mono<String> and it's now doing what I want. Cheers!